# What is ".xsession" for?

Tags: xorg, x11, login

What is the purpose of the `.xsession` file in the home folder? What should be put in there? The desktop environments don't use that file and for the X startup from the tty there is `.xinitrc`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you log in in text mode then start a GUI session with [xinit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinit) or with the wrapper script `startx`, then `xinit` does the following things:

- Start an X server (typically through the script `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`).
- Usually run some scripts in `/etc/X11` (typically `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`), depending on how it's set up.
- Run `~/.xinitrc`, if it exists. If it doesn't exist, run a default client (traditionally `xterm`).
- Once `~/.xinitrc` terminates, kill the X server.

If you log in in graphical mode on an [X display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29) (xdm, gdm, kdm, wdm, lightdm, …),  traditionally, what is executed after you log in is some scripts in `/etc/X11` then `~/.xsession`.

`~/.xsession` has the role of `~/.profile` and `~/.xinitrc` combined: it's supposed to perform the initial startup of your session (e.g. define environment variables), then launch programs specific to the GUI (usually at least window manager).

Nowadays, most X display managers give you a choice of a session. Choosing a particular session launched a specific desktop environment, session manager, window manager. What is executed then is only that DE/SM/WM and whatever programs it chooses to start based on whatever configuration files it chooses to read. Many environments provide a “custom session” that reads the traditional `~/.xsession`.

Comment: I don't know what is this "many environments", but at least kdm silently ignores the «~/.xsession» file.

Comment: @Hi-Angel The `.xsession` file is only read if you select a particular session type. I know that for Gdm, the upstream developers don't want to include one that runs `.xsession` by default, and leave it up to each distribution, and many distributions don't bother or don't realize the need. I don't know what the kdm situation is.

Comment: Well, you know, I [found in man kdm](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/kdm/) that kdm have an own file `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession` to be ran as user just after login. They're lie — the file *(which is present btw)* never being touched by kdm, I even did removed it at all, and that didn't changed anything.

Comment: @Hi-Angel What Gilles means is that at your graphical login screen you'll often have a dropdown menu listing various environments. If you choose "KDE," that will start and it will ignore `.xsession`, as you described. But if, instead of "KDE," you choose "Custom session," `.xsession` will be run _instead of_ KDE. I use this, for example, because I run just `xfce4-panel` and FVWM 2 as my "desktop"; if KDE were installed on a system I happened to be using, it would be completely ignored.

Comment: Xsession may setup paths. Since it's often run from startx typed at a command line, frequently all paths are already set up.

Comment: I need to setxkbmap and found `/etc/gdm3/Xsession` will change it. And I have to set it at the very end to make it work.

Answer (score 19):

X session startup can be complicated these days.  A good place to start is the script `/etc/X11/Xsession` to see how things will get executed.

On my Debian/Ubuntu systems, the script `/etc/X11/Xsession` sets the variable `USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession`.  Later, the script `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50x11-common_determine-startup` looks for this script and uses it as the primary session, if allowed by system policy in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`, and if no other session was requested by the display manager.

Comment: Complicated is an understatement. Combined with sys specific handling of /etc/ profile  etc it's a downright mess.

Comment: And there have been a lot of changes in the 8 years since this answer was posted (such as systemd adoption).

Comment: @JimParis My `/etc/X11/Xsession` sets the variable `USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession`, used by `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50x11-common_determine-startup`. My `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` has `allow-user-xsession`. But still my `${HOME}/.xsession` doesn't run as I did `echo "Hello Nikhil"  > /home/nikhil/Desktop/a.txt` inside `${HOME}/.xsession` but this file is not created when I log in after logging out! Can you please help? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2. I want to start firefox using systemd unit and I am refering https://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg/1128905#1128905

Answer (score 10):

I strongly recommend you to take a look in the book *X Window system administrator's guide : for X version 11*. Chapter 2 explains the purpose of `.xsession` and the whole configuration process for a sample setup. Also it's a nice refresher for the whole x-window related terminology (and i hope you don't get spooked :) ). You can get the book from

> http://archive.org/details/xwindowsystemadm08muimiss

Although it's rather outdated you can find a lot of information of the underlying concepts that didn't change until today and it is very legible. Moreover it is really funny to take a look at what was top notch at those days.

Answer (score 8):

.xsession is the traditional startscript for the X11 environment. Nowadays with sessionmanagers like kdm it is not that much of a use anymore, but on a traditionaly set up system. This is what is run after starting X11 with startx.

Comment: It is one of many things depending on system and xinitrc as well as /x11 xsession