# Can't seem to add `tint2` to the startup process in Arch Linux with Openbox

Tags: arch-linux, openbox

I've already tried adding it as an entry in the `~/.xinitrc` and even in the `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file.

I tried adding it as the following variants:

```
tint2
tint2 &
tint2 -c ~/dotfiles/linux/tint2rc
tint2 -c ~/dotfiles/linux/tint2rc &
```

None of them work in both files. Of course none of these at the same time, or in both files at the same time. With the first two I get errors regarding not finding the configuration file, so I just tell it where it is, even though there's a perfectly working symlink where it should be. :)

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Or is it just not working as it should?

Just thought I would note. After Openbox starts up, I can open any terminal and run `tint2 -c ~/dotfiles/linux/tint2rc` and it'll run just fine, immediately. However if I close that Terminal the process is terminated...

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I have ``tint2 &`` in /home/nylon100/.config/openbox/autostart and it works fine.

Comment: @nylon100 Thanks for that! It's possible it's a specific issue with my install then. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to answer without seeing your .xinitrc, but assuming you're just calling the Openbox binary at the end, try this:

```
exec /path/to/wm & WMPID=$!
/path/to/tint2 --options &
# other bits
wait $WMPID
```

I use dbus to launch my WindowManager these days because of all that tight systemd integration, the above works nicely too.

Comment: Yes I am only calling `openbox-session` in my .xinitrc. So basically what this is doing is call Openbox, tint2 and other stuff, and then making it wait?

Comment: Yep - the first line executes your WM and collects the resulting PID in a variable. `wait` will instruct BASH to wait for the process and then return the exit code it returned.The theory in your case being that tint2 requires a Window Manager to be running.

Comment: So the first line should be `exec openbox-session & WMPID=$!`? Also would this work in Zsh? I use Zsh.

Comment: Correct on both counts. Although, I use a BASH shebang for my `.xinitrc`. Old habits etc.

Comment: Tried it, and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, adding these lines to `~/.config/openbox/autostart` should work. Unfortunately, I don't have openbox installed so I can't check.

However, I *can* tell you why it does not work with `~/.xinitrc`. `~/.xinitrc` is only read when you are launching X manually from a tty using `startx` or `xinit` (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47426/22222)). When you log in from a graphical loigin manager, it is ignored and `~/.xsession` is read instead. So, try adding the relevant lines to your `~/.xsession` file instead.

Comment: Oops yes. Yes I am adding these entries to this file (autostart), not the other one (startup). A typo I just fixed. :P

Comment: @Eduan ah, not that simple a solution then :). Try the `.xsession` suggestion.

Comment: I do use `startx` though, haven't taken the time to use a login manager yet. I'm the type that prefers control where it doesn't matter as much. :P

Comment: Perhaps it is starting too soon? Try adding a `sleep` in case tint2 depends on services that are loaded a bit later (I'm thinking of the systray).

Comment: I tried adding `sleep 10` to the line right above the one with the tint2 stuff. Didn't make a difference, and by that point it should have already loaded, since it does load in that time if I start it manually...