# Keep getting the same result after "export PATH"

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path

I am doing this:

```
$ which cabal
/usr/bin/cabal
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin
$ which cabal
/usr/bin/cabal
```

I expect to get `/.cabal/bin/cabal` for `$ which cabal` (this path exists) after this. But I don't even after re-opening the terminal. How come?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paths in `$PATH` are searched in order.  This allows you to override a system default with:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

`$HOME/bin` is now the *first* (highest priority) path.  You did it the other way around, making it the *last* (lowest priority) path.  When the shell goes looking, it uses the first match it finds.

In case it's not clear, this all works by concatenating strings.  An analogy:

```
WORD=bar
WORD=foo$WORD
```

`$WORD` is now `foobar`.  The `:` used with `$PATH` is literal, which you can see with `echo $PATH`.

Comment: and what do I do?

Comment: Use `export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH` -- with `$PATH` *after* `$HOME/.cabal/bin`.  In case it's not clear, this works by concatenating the old value of `$PATH` with some new value(s).  Analogy: `WORD=bar; WORD=foo$WORD` -> `$WORD` is now `foobar`.  WRT `$PATH`, **don't forget the colon in between.**

Comment: and how do I remove the one I've already added?

Comment: In other words, how do I redo this export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin ?

Comment: If you did it on the command line, you can just `exit` the shell/terminal you're using -- `export` applies it to the current shell and all its children, not everything that's running.  If you put it in `.bash_profile` or something, just change it and log in again.  In any case, it's harmless to add the path at the beginning and leave it at the end as well.

Comment: so running this in the terminal doesn't make it persistent? Where do I have to add the line `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` - in the beginning or in the end of .bash_profile?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that would work.

Comment: @Volodya, this isn't a yes/no question.

Comment: Put it at the end if there is anything predefined in that file.  If it doesn't work after you log in, you'll need to source it from an `.xsession` file or put it in `.bashrc`, in which case you may want to read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/how-can-i-cleanly-add-to-path

Comment: ...the issue is that some graphical login systems ("display managers") don't source `.bash_profile`, but they do use `.xsession` -- so if you `source ~/.bash_profile` in `~/.xsession` it will work. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/what-is-xsession-for