# Debian continue running script from lxde even after logging off

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, lxde

I'm trying to play some games on Steam (specifically *Half-Life 2*), but having Xinerama enabled with my dual monitor setup results in the infamous:

```
Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
```

I found a solution at the [archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1296900#p1296900), but I'm having trouble implementing it into a shell script with LXDE.

```
#!/usr/sh
pkill -SIGTERM -f xsession
startx -- -layout Steam
```

It logs me out successfully with `pkill` but then I'm returned to a console prompt and `startx` is never executed. What am I missing here?

```
user@home:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/91-serverlayout-steam.conf
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 340.46  (pbuilder@zam904)  Fri Oct 17 21:29:34 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Steam"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VS248"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460 v2"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running that script from within LXDE?

If so, when you kill your session and LXDE shuts down, the script is terminated as well as its a child of the LXDE session.

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to start a parent script from within the LXDE session?

Comment: The "parent" script would be .xinitrc or .xession - which is called when starting X. Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/what-is-xsession-for  
  
The simplest solution could just be to jump to a console, then execute that script.

Comment: The [XineramaHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo) uses this command: `startx /path/to/the/game -- :1 -config xorg.conf.single` ... if I'm already at console then instead of having to create a [CustomXSession](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession) isn't running `startx` pretty much the same thing?

Comment: That'd work fine, the key point being that you're running it from a console outside of your LXDE session, with X not running.

Comment: Ah I see, so I guess there's no way to continue the script if it was initially called in the `xsession` that would be terminating. Thank you for clarifying!